# which config will change the direction and language of html document in Nuxt 3?

Tags: nuxtjs3

I want to change my document direction and language, but don't want to do that with JS. how can I do that?

Is there any config for that?
how to set document direction to RTL?

```html
<!doctype html>
<html dir="rtl" lang="fa">
  <!-- another tags -->
</html>
```

Comment: No one know what you mean about "direction", besides you need to give us some code examples what you want to achieve or what did you do till now.

Comment: HTML global attribute dir . is there another direction? how can I set it to RTL?

Comment: You may want to consider using Bootstrap for it's "RTL" capabilities: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/getting-started/rtl/

Comment: @sadeqshahmoradi You are not changing head in `nuxt.config.js` file. You hard code it.

Comment: I understand but my website has a single language so there is no need for dynamic `lang` or `dir` attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nuxt3 use `@vueuse/head`. You don't need to download, it's already in Nuxt3.

**It will be something like that:**

```js
useHead({
    htmlAttrs: { dir: 'rtl', lang: 'fa' },
})
```

Works well with SSR in Nuxt3.

Also, you can hard code it in your `nuxt.config.ts` if you don't need more languages:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    app: {
        head: {
            htmlAttrs: { dir: 'rtl', lang: 'fa' },
        },
    },
})
```